# onreadystatechange vs load/domcontentloaded events efficiency

Tags: performance, dom, browser, dom-events

I've just realised that the code I'm going through sometimes uses `load/DOMcontentloaded` events and sometimes uses the `onreadystatechange` event.
I'm trying to uniformize it but I really don't know which one is better (I'm thinking about performance and resource use for mobile).

The only difference I can see is that `onreadystatechange` always applies to `document` and `load/DOMcontentloaded` is applied to `window/document`.
Does this mean that the way browsers implement them is different and matters or is this just a "too much" engineered question?

Comment: have u found answer to this?